# Symfony2 - variable from controller to listener

Tags: php, symfony

I have a situation I am trying to resolve.  I have a controller with a standard createAction

```
 public function createAction(Request $request)
 {
    try {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $alert = new AvailabilityAlert();
        $alert->setLastUpdated();
        $alert->setIsDeleted(0);
        $alert->setAlertStatus('Active');

        $em->persist($alert);
        $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse('Success');

    }catch (Exception $e) {
    }

}
```

I then have an event listener for this action

```
<?php

namespace Nick\AlertBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;
use Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlert;
use Nick\AlertBundle\Service\UapiService;

class AvailabilityAlertListener
{
    protected $api_service;

    public function __construct(UapiService $api_service)
    {
        $this->api_service = $api_service;
    }

    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();

        foreach ($em->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
            if ($entity instanceof AvailabilityAlert) {
                var_dump($entity->getId());
                $this->api_service->addFlightsAction($entity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This event listener calls addFlightAction.  This is simply

```
public function addFlightsAction($alert){
    $em = $this->sc->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $worldspanCommand = $em->getRepository("NickAlertBundle:AvailabilityAlert")->getSpecificAlert($alert->getId());

}
```

This calls a custom repo and is using the id of the newly created alert.  The function is

```
public function getSpecificAlert($id)
{
    $active = "Active";

    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT a.id, a.searchCommand,
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.classLetter) AS classes,
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.pseudo) AS pseudos,
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.flightNumber) AS flight_number
                    FROM NickAlertBundle:AvailabilityAlert a
                        JOIN NickAlertBundle:AvailabilityAlertBookingClass c
                          WITH a.id = c.availabilityAlert
                        JOIN NickAlertBundle:AvailabilityAlertPseudos p
                          WITH a.id = p.availabilityAlert
                        JOIN NickAlertBundle:AvailabilityAlertFlightNumbers f
                          WITH a.id = f.availabilityAlert
                    WHERE a.alertStatus = :active
                    AND a.id = :id
                    GROUP BY a.id'
        )
        ->setParameter('active', $active)
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getResult();
}
```

If I var_dump the result of the above query, I get an empty response.  If I change the setParameter for id to $id-1 then it gives me the correct response but for the last added alert, not the current one.  So the query works, but not with the current id.  So this tells me by the time this query is executed, the alert is not in the database?

**UPDATE**

I cant find much information on postFlush, but this does not seem to fire the var_dump

```
public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();

    foreach ($em->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
        if ($entity instanceof AvailabilityAlert) {
            var_dump("TEST");
            $this->api_service->addFlightsAction($entity);
        }
    }
}
```

I dont get any error though.

Comment: Is primary key generated automatically or not?

Answer (score 2):

OnFlush is triggered/catched before actually flushing the entities. So no id is available yet.

Try to use postFlush event instead. You will find all available events in doctrine documentation.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html

Answer (score 2):

postPersist is enaugh, I know you have tried but I'm sure you are messing up something. This because:

> postPersist - The postPersist event occurs for an entity after the
> entity has been made persistent. It will be invoked after the database
> insert operations. **Generated primary key values are available in the
> postPersist event.**

from http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html

So, to me, you haven't assigned a value for PK to your entity. Or something is not correctly configured

---

### Update

After OP updated the question, is pretty clear that only way to reach what he wants is to listen on `postFlush()` event.

I also suggest to pass only integer `$id` to `addFlightsAction()` as it seems that you do nothing with whole `$entity` object

Comment: I have added how my id is generated.  I initially had this set up with a postPersist, only recently moved to the flush.

Comment: Give me a few minutes, the id is coming correctly now with a postPersist.  However, I have a different problem occurring now which would lead me to believe the Object is not in the database yet.  I will get this added to the original post.

Comment: I have redone my original post.  The id is fine, but the query does not work on the current id which tells me it is not in the database yet.

Comment: @NickPrice what query? Please update your question with some relevant code and errors. It's not first time I told you, isn't it? :)

Comment: Oh, I did update the original question, I changed it to the new problem.

Comment: Persisting the entities does not commit any insert/update/delete action on them. That's why your query does not work. Using postPersit, you are relying on an nonexistent id. It needs to be flushed.

Comment: @GrégoryElhaimer: you're wrong. Although persist() method will not write anything onto db, but only tell doctrine2 to manage that object for persistence operations, postPersist() is called after db insertion. Please take a look to documentation I've linked.

Comment: I did not said the query were not executed. I said it was not commited which implies that entry is not accessible yet. That's why using post persist does not make you able to query the said entity. Since it's not commited yet (no flush processed) you can not query it. Doc does only say it is triggered after insert query. Not after it is commited which is flush method's responsability.

Comment: @GrégoryElhaimer: Yes, you're right but I've not seen yet update from OP's question and didn't get you're talking about "commit". Before question edit my answer was good, now that I can seen it will rely on db data, I' will suggest to use other hook.

Comment: Yeah my bad wanted to up vote, but missed the small button. Corrected :p